# html link focus and hover states does not work properly with css column-count in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When i use css column-count i get the following focus issue:

Part of the outline is shown in the previous column (see image)

[image]

code example:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  
  column-count: 3;
}

li {
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-underline-offset: 3px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">dasdasdas sadasda asdasdas asdasda</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dasdasdas sadasda asda</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dasdasdas sadasda asdas asdasda sadasd</a></li>

<li><a href="#">dasdasdas sadasda asdasdas asdasda</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dasdasdas sadasda asda</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dasdasdas sadasda asdas asdasda sadasd</a></li>

<li><a href="#">dasdasdas sadasda asdasdas asdasda</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dasdasdas sadasda asda</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dasdasdas sadasda asdas asdasda sadasd</a></li>

</ul>
```

and an other issue is the hover state dont work properly because of css text-underline-offset in combinaton with column-count. hover state does not go away when you go to other link.

[image]

Any idee why and how to fix this issues? (these issues are only in chrome browser)

Comment: i run in chrome and it does not happend to me. can you explain more(maybe it about the screen size)

Comment: my chrome version is 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit) on windows 10. and the issue comes here in all screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding padding to the top of each anchor element - in my case I had to add roughly 3px of padding, if that helps.